# split a string from a set of substrings in panda frames

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am working on a data set from various sources and I have column is the frame that captures for example City Names. Certain city names have the name of the state in parentheses, others have the zip code. How do I get ride of those extra info and keep the city names only?
[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t05xk.jpg)

In certain cases, there is no space between zip code and cityname.
Below is the desired frame:
[Desired frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWuUy.jpg)

Comment: I am looking for a simple way to drop the string from ' (' or a number between 0-9

Comment: Please include all your data in the question (do not paste links to screenshots). Also include all you code and _specific_ code-related questions.

Comment: The data is pretty big, but here is an example

df = pd.DataFrame([{'City Name': 'Dallas'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'New York (NY)'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'West Orange 07052'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'Orlando (Florda)'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'Camdem (NJ)'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'Boston'}
                   ,{'City Name': 'Harrison07029'}])

And I want to just get the city names

Comment: As I said, please include all relevant data in the question, not in the comments. Add the code that you tried to use, explain why you are not happy with it, and ask _specific_ questions. That's how SO works.

Comment: Sorry DYZ, I am pretty new here. I was trying to use a lambda that splits from one the sub strings and apply it to the panda, but it wasn't working.
The response provided by jezrael worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by regex:

- `\s*` for one or zero space
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `\(.*\)` all strings between + parentheses

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'City Name': 'Dallas'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'New York (NY)'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'West Orange 07052'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'Orlando (Florda)'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'Camdem (NJ)'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'Boston'} ,
                   {'City Name': 'Harrison07029'}])

df['new'] = df['City Name'].replace(['\s*\d+', '\s*\(.*\)'], '', regex=True)
print (df)
           City Name          new
0             Dallas       Dallas
1      New York (NY)     New York
2  West Orange 07052  West Orange
3   Orlando (Florda)      Orlando
4        Camdem (NJ)       Camdem
5             Boston       Boston
6      Harrison07029     Harrison
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, I was trying to use split, and forgot about replace.